# How to create a custom tabbed view like the one on the peach app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, material-design

I want to recreate a tabbed view that looks like this, my problem is how can I make it float and make it so it has that material look.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeCmS.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use and customize material design elements. Feel free to use [Material](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material) library it is easy to implement and customize.

Comment: Thanks! Thats actually really helpful!